# How to save and load model of tf.estimator.BoostedTreesRegressor in the Tensorflow version='2.0.0'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am New to the  tf.estimator.BoostedTreesRegressor.. Here is the sample code that I have used to built the model.

```
n_batches = 20

est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesRegressor(feature_columns,
                                           n_batches_per_layer=n_batches , learning_rate=0.001, n_trees=700,
                                            max_depth=13, 
model_dir = "model", tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(60))

est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=10)
```

I want to save the model.. and load latter the model to predict the sales.

Can you please help me with how to do this in the TensorFlow version 2.. as I was not able to find...

Thanks

Comment: Check solution provided here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959582/saving-loading-and-predicting-from-a-tensorflow-estimator-model-2-0/60230173#comment118347400_60230173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should be saved in the `model_dir` path according to the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesClassifier). Please specify a real directory path to `model_dir` while instantiating BoostedTreesRegressor.

Furthermore, you can save model using `export_saved_model` method.

```
# Saving estimator model
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
  tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns))
export_path = estimator.export_saved_model("/dir/path/", serving_input_fn)
```

For loading saved model you can use `saved_model.load` function as follows:

```
#loading saved model
imported = tf.saved_model.load(export_path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Awesome, the codes that you shared is working..

Comment: @Kaushik Roy after loading the model how to do prediction? There is no prediction method while we load the model in this way though