# Saving, loading, and predicting from a TensorFlow Estimator model (2.0)

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a guide anywhere for serializing and restoring `Estimator` models in TF2? The documentation is very spotty, and much of it not updated to TF2. I've yet to see a clear ands complete example anywhere of an `Estimator` being saved, loaded from disk and used to predict from new inputs.

TBH, I'm a bit baffled by how complicated this appears to be. Estimators are billed as simple, relatively high-level ways of fitting standard models, yet the process for using them in production seems very arcane. For example, when I load a model from disk via `tf.saved_model.load(export_path)` I get an `AutoTrackable` object:

`<tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable at 0x7fc42e779f60>`

Its not clear why I don't get my `Estimator` back. It looks like there used to be a useful-sounding function `tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model`, but since `contrib` is gone, it does not appear to be in play anymore (except, it appears, in TFLite).

Any pointers would be very helpful. As you can see, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [`tf.saved_model.load`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load) in 2.0? It is different to [the 1.x version](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/saved_model/load). The section "Importing SavedModels from TensorFlow 1.x" applies to estimators, and explains how to obtain a callable to evaluate the model with `prune`.

Comment: OK, this may be part of the confusion, as I'm not using TensorFlow 1.x. In those docs, there is no clear exposition on how to get my `Estimator` (a `DNNRegression` in my case) back.

Comment: It may be that I've made a mistake in using `Estimator`s for what I'm trying to do. Perhaps I should be using the Keras interface exclusively. I just want to generate a few models, serialize them, and then load them as needed to make predictions.

Comment: Ah so you want to retrieve the actual estimator object, not just be able to load the model and run it, is that right? Yes, there does not seem to be an API for that, only for [running models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#savedmodels_from_estimators) in general or for [Keras models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format)... With Keras is easier in general, and if you need the estimator interface you can [make an estimator from a Keras model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimator#create_an_estimator_from_a_keras_model).

Comment: `I'm a bit baffled by how complicated this appears to be` <-- so true.  keras makes everything harder, not easier. :)

Comment: If you just recreate the same Estimator (same model_fn, or same canned Estimator with same arguments), and reuse the same output directory, it will reload and be ready to use `.predict`. If you don't want or have the source code to recreate the same Estimator, saved_model.load will give you an object you can query (use for prediction) but that object will not have the Estimator API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maybe the author doesn't need the answer anymore but I was able to save and load a DNNClassifier using TensorFlow 2.1

```py
# training.py
from pathlib import Path
import tensorflow as tf

....
# Creating the estimator
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    model_dir= < model_dir >,
    hidden_units = [1000, 500],
    feature_columns = feature_columns,  # this is a list defined earlier
    n_classes = 2,
    optimizer = 'adam'
)

feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
servable_model_path = Path(estimator.export_saved_model( < model_dir >, export_input_fn).decode('utf8'))
print(f'Model saved at {servable_model_path}')
```

For loading, you found the correct method, you just need to retrieve the `predict_fn`

```py
# testing.py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

def predict_input_fn(test_df):
    '''Convert your dataframe using tf.train.Example() and tf.train.Features()'''
    examples = []
    ....
    return tf.constant(examples)

test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', ...)

# Loading the estimator
predict_fn = tf.saved_model.load(<model_dir>).signatures['predict']
# Predict
predictions = predict_fn(examples=predict_input_fn(test_df))
```

Hope that this can help other people too (:

Comment: I did give up on using Estimators entirely, but this will be a useful reference for others. I will accept the answer.

Comment: I can't believe how troublesome it is to do simple things such as saving and loading models with the current Estimator API. Pytorch is so simple and intuitive in comparison.

Comment: Hey @Omar Contugno, could you please elaborate on how to `Convert your dataframe using tf.train.Example() and tf.train.Features()`? Im having trouble with this step of your answer.

Comment: I used the code provided here: http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/05/14/serve-tensorflow-estimator-with-savedmodel/ to convert from `df-->tf.constant(examples)`

Comment: what about scala/java?