# save and load model in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I saved a model from premade estimator in tensorflow 2.x with this code

```
import os
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(my_feature_columns))
estimator_base_path = os.path.join( 'from_estimator')
estimator_path = classifier.export_saved_model(estimator_base_path, serving_input_fn)
```

this code create a folder which contains a .pb file
i need to reuse this model in the future, i try to load woth this function

```
saved_model_obj = tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load(export_dir="/model_dir/")
```

but when i try to make a prediction on using the loaded model it raises this error

```
predictions = saved_model_obj.predict(
input_fn=lambda: input_fn(predict_x))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a9902ff8210c> in <module>
----> 1 predictions = saved_model_obj.predict(
      2     input_fn=lambda: input_fn(predict_x))

AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

how can i load a .pb file and make prediction, like if i've never saved and loaded it?

Comment: Check solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959582/saving-loading-and-predicting-from-a-tensorflow-estimator-model-2-0/60230173#comment118347400_60230173

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving, loading, and predicting from a TensorFlow Estimator model (2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959582/saving-loading-and-predicting-from-a-tensorflow-estimator-model-2-0)

Answer (score -1):

When I save models for later use I usually do this:

Assuming that your model is `model`:

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

This will save the modoel in a hdf5 format.

Then when I have to use it to predict again I can just:

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
```

and than you can `new_model.predict()`

Comment: i'm using a premade estimator, in particular DNNClassifier. It's not a keras model

Comment: As far as you can load it in a model object and train it you can save it in a hdf5 file

Comment: when loaded with the function tf.compat.v2.saved_model.load it is not a model object, it is an Autotrackable object